# add an image to a html type input check box or radio

Tags: html, input, checkbox, radio-button

I'm trying to specify an image to be used for my unchecked and checked values for html input type checkbox and radio.

I have got this:

```
background: url("image.png") no-repeat;
```

but it doesnt seem to work on radio and checkbox only button.

Does anyone know something that will work?

Comment: Hope it isn't due to positioning, as the check box is very small in relation to a button? The image background, though applied, may have been hidden due to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [Ryan Fait - Custom checkboxes and radio buttons](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) ... Hope it's what you're looking for ;)

Comment: i have seen this but it looks a little complex and i wondered if there was a simpler way?

Comment: Don't know about any but don't be afraid, it is not as complicated as it seems

Comment: i have just tried to get that ryan fait thing to work but the images never work.

Comment: Well, that's strange, I made it work without any extreme effort. There must be "the little something" that's wrong and that forces it not to work.

Comment: I made it work, but I cannot manage to hide the "old" checkbox image. It shows both checkboxes, the one that I've created and the regular checkbox one. Any help with it?

Answer (score 5):

I have found and worked an answer.
with help from these forums
http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=665980

all code is below: you can copy to a single file and add your own images and it will work.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
//global variables that can be used by ALL the function son this page.
var inputs;
var imgFalse = '52 0 ROff.png';
var imgTrue = '52 0 ROn.png';

//replace the checkbox with an image and setup events to handle it
function replaceChecks() {
    //get all the input fields on the page
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    //cycle trough the input fields
    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {

    //check if the input is a checkbox
    if(inputs[i].getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox') {

        //create a new image
        var img = document.createElement('img');

        //check if the checkbox is checked
        if(inputs[i].checked) {
            img.src = imgTrue;
        } else {
            img.src = imgFalse;
        }

        //set image ID and onclick action
        img.id = 'checkImage'+i;
        //set image
        img.onclick = new Function('checkClick('+i+')');

        //place image in front of the checkbox
        inputs[i].parentNode.insertBefore(img, inputs[i]);

        //hide the checkbox
        inputs[i].style.display='none';
    }
}
}

//change the checkbox status and the replacement image
function checkClick(i) {
if(inputs[i].checked) {
    inputs[i].checked = '';
    document.getElementById('checkImage'+i).src=imgFalse;
} else {
    inputs[i].checked = 'checked';
    document.getElementById('checkImage'+i).src=imgTrue;
}
}

</script>
</html>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" />
<script type="text/javascript">replaceChecks();</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Worked perfect, without any issues. I just was confused at the beginning because you wrote the name of the images with spaces. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In checkbox if you want to change images or/and color then the optimized way is **http://jsfiddle.net/nsoni/4cHSB/5/** here you can click either on "item name" or on "checkbox" and get the effect.

HTML:

```
  <div class="had">
        <div class="ch">
            <input type="checkbox" id="sho1" name="chk1">
            <div class="so"></div>
            <label for="sho1">Select one</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ch">
            <input type="checkbox" id="sho2" name="chk2">
            <div class="so"></div>
            <label for="sho2">Select two</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    input {
               display: none;
    }

        input [type=checkbox]:checked+.so{
              background-image:url('http://goo.gl/3tza1X');
              background-repeat:no-repeat;background-color:green;
              border-radius:50%;background-position: -2px -1px;
    }

        input [type=checkbox]:checked+.so+label{
           color: red;
    }

        .so {
             margin: 2px; float: left;height: 30px;width: 30px;
             border: 3px solid #D8D8D8;background-color: #4679BD;
             border-radius: 5px;
    }

        .show {
               margin-left: 30px;
    }

        .had {
               margin: 50px auto;width: 50%;border: 1px solid black;
               height: 30px;padding:10px;
    }

        .ch {
              float: left;margin-left:20px;width:40%
    }

        label {
               height: 30px;width: 100%;position:relative;
               display:block;margin-top: 5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot style checkboxes and radio buttons by pure CSS. You will need to get a JavaScript plugin (there are plenty of jQuery plugins out there) which will do this for you. Basically, it overlays another element over the default one by keeping the default element's behaviour.

Comment: so there is no way in css to add images to radio and check boxes, whats the simplest way to do it with javascript

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it. I'm using radio input. The input boxes are hidden and the image in each label changes when the input is selected/not selected.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EhDsf/

HTML:

```
<div class="options">
    <label title="item1">
        <input type="radio" name="foo" value="0" /> 
      Item 1
        <img />

   </label>
    <label title="item2">
        <input type="radio" name="foo" value="1" />
        Item 2
        <img />
    </label>   
    <label title="item3">
        <input type="radio" name="foo" value="2" />
        Item 3
        <img />
    </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.options > label > input {
    visibility: hidden;
}

div.options > label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
    padding: 0 0 48px 0;  
    height: 20px;
    width: 150px;

}

div.options > label > img {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    background: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/snipicons/500/thumbs-down-128.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:60px 60px;
}

div.options > label > input:checked +img {  
    background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/onebit/PNG/onebit_34.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:60px 60px;
}
```