# How to put an image on a radio button in HTML

Tags: css, html, radio-button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [add an image to a html type input check box or radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117116/add-an-image-to-a-html-type-input-check-box-or-radio)

Hi,
I want to make a rating div using radio buttons in HTML .. I want users to look at a picture and rate it. So, I want to use  and have a star image on each one ..

I searched every where and couldnt do it. I found one topic here that use javascript to do this .. But it was not efficient and it made my icons extremely large

[add an image to a html type input check box or radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117116/add-an-image-to-a-html-type-input-check-box-or-radio)

Comment: The duplicate you point to is exactly the same question, though, isn't it? Please follow up on that one - the solutions shown there should work, and "icons too large" sounds like something that can be fixed. If it doesn't work out for you, rather ask a specific question about fixing the icon size

Comment: Is this [thread](http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/740183-making-image-part-radio-button) useful ?

Comment: I agree with @Pekka.  Please try out the solutions on the other question and let us know specifically what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery, see this link :
[jQuery Star Rating Plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/)

If you want to use if with ASP.NET, you can use Ajax Control Toolkit, see this link:
[Ajax Rating Sample](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Rating/Rating.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This article will help: [Styling Checkboxes and Radio Buttons With CSS and JavaScript](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/).

But this one is better: [Accessible, Custom Designed Checkbox and Radio Button Inputs Styled with CSS (and a dash of jQuery)](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/accessible_custom_designed_checkbox_radio_button_inputs_styled_css_jquery/).