# Check box replaced by an image after on click in HTML

Tags: html

I want to add image in check box in HTML so that when i click on check box it should be replaced by an image.What is the way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [add an image to a html type input check box or radio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117116/add-an-image-to-a-html-type-input-check-box-or-radio)

Answer (score 0):

Let cb be a checkbox, and src the source of the image you want to be displayed.

```
cb.onclick = function(){
    if(!this.img){
        var img = this.img = document.createElement("image");
        img.src=src;
        img.cb = this;
        img.onclick = function(){
            this.parentNode.replaceChild(this.cb,this);
            }
        }
    this.parentNode.replaceChild(this.img,this);
    }
```